# What can cause a "Security Error" when uploading a file to zippyshare?

Tags: upload, zippyshare

I am trying to upload a file (zip archive) to zippyshare and I get a "Security Error":

[image]

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall security options might cause this issue.